# Node.js map returning result between quotes and brackets in Slack window

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, slack

I am building a Slack app that has a slash command for displaying data from the database using `pg-promise` module like this:

```
select: () =>
    rep.map(sql.select, null, row => {
        return 'User ' + row.username + ' is ' + row.status;
    }),
```

Like this, an array of rows is returned, but the result is always like:

```
["User username1 is status1", "User username2 is status2", ...]
```

I need it to be displayed in a list,  without these quotes and brackets.

```
User username1 is status1
User username2 is status2
...
```

I've tried to `replace` using regex, but it doesn't work.

Comment: how do you call `select` function ?

Comment: That's console presentation for an array of strings. If you display individual strings, they will be shown without wrapping quotes. So what is really your question?

Comment: @vitaly-t How to display without quotes and brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intent is simply to display the resulting strings:

```
var os = require('os');

rep.map(sql.select, null, row => {
    return 'User ' + row.username + ' is ' + row.status;
})
    .then(data=> {
        console.log(data.join(os.EOL));
    });
```

[Database.map](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.map) resolves with a new array of returned values, the same as your regular [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

I think your result is a JavaScript array, so you have to iterate on it in order to display it as you expect.

you should assign `select()` result to a `var` so you can iterate that `var`

```
var results = select();
for(var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
     console.log(results[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var results = select();
var resultText = select.join('\n');
// console.log(resultText);
```

Now `resultText` will be a single string with each message separated by a newline.